# How to use JavaScript to validate text box with popup notification?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this JavaScript code to validate a text box, but when the alert popup appears and the user presses okay it returns to the page and the submit button is disabled so when the user clicks submit no action occurs, any ideas?

```
if (document.getElementById('Title').value == "") {
    alert('Please fill mobile number');
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); //prevent default form submit

        });
    });
}
```

this line is the problem:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

I need substitutes please

Comment: why are using submit handler [$("form").submit()] inside the validation logic? and when does the validation code run?

Comment: why do you have a document ready inside your validation? it makes no sense.

Comment: the point was is submit button would be disabled from post action , but its okay now just forgot "return false"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $("form").submit(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();  
     if (document.getElementById('Title').value == "") {
        alert('Please fill mobile number');
        return false;
     }
});
```

in your code, validation and form submission working on separate.

Comment: and no need to e.preventDefault();

Comment: @Muthaan , if you why the popup appears more than once sometimes ?

Comment: $("form").submit(function (e) {
     if (document.getElementById('Title').value == "") {
        alert('Please fill mobile number');
        return false;
     }
});

Comment: its just the same u suggest but without this line "e.preventDefault();"